# Como sumar un valor de una tabla a otra tabla con django

Tags: python, django, django-models, djangorestframework, django-admin

el punto es hacer un asiento contable. estoy usando el admin de django y cuando creo un asiento debo usar dos cuentas (que ya existen en la tabla cuenta) y a esas sumarle o restarle el valor que ingreso en el asiento(total), la cosa es que llevo recien 3 dias usando python y django y no se si esto es posible o existe alguna forma de hacerlo.

Este es el models.py

```
class Asiento(models.Model):
def __str__(self):
    return self.descripcion
id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
fecha = models.CharField(db_column='FECHA', max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
descripcion = models.CharField(db_column='DESCRIPCION', max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
factura = models.CharField(db_column='FACTURA', max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
ctadebito = models.ForeignKey('Cuenta', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CTADEBITO', blank=True, null=True, related_name='debito')  # Field name made lowercase.
ctacredito = models.ForeignKey('Cuenta', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CTACREDITO', blank=True, null=True, related_name='credito')  # Field name made lowercase.
total = models.FloatField(db_column='TOTAL', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

class Cuenta(models.Model):
def __str__(self):
    return self.descripcion
codigo = models.IntegerField(db_column='CODIGO', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
descripcion = models.CharField(db_column='DESCRIPCION', max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
saldo = models.FloatField(db_column='SALDO', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, puedes hacerlo con una [Expresión F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F). En base al objeto `Asiento` puedes hacer algo así:

```
from django.db.models import F

asiento = Asiento.objects.all().get(id=1)
asiento.ctadebito.saldo = F("saldo") - asiento.total
asiento.ctacredito.saldo = F("saldo") + asiento.total
asiento.ctadebito.save(update_fields=["saldo"])
asiento.ctacredito.save(update_fields=["saldo"])
```

He utilizado `update_fields` en el método `save()` para evitar actualizar todo el registro.

Comment: genial, fuiste de gran ayuda